# How to use #define guards in a static code analysis-friendly way?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

We currently use a `#ifdef DEPLOYED` to identify deploy builds of our c++17 project and change the behavior.

However, static code analysis, e.g. inside the IDE frequently (and on a first glance rightfully) warns of unused variables, which in the past I have rashly removed just to later find out in our nightly that the deploy built failed (because in our CI, the testing is done on non-deploy builds, only the nightly deployment builds with the flag turned on).

One of the many examples was:

```
catch (std::exception& e) {
#if defined(DEPLOYED)
    std::cerr << "Exception doing something " << e.what() << std::endl;
#else
    throw;
#endif
}
```

On a developer machine, `e` was never used, so a warning arose, `catch (std::exception& e) {` was changed to `catch (std::exception&) {` thus failing deploy builds.

How could this be written differently? One solution I had in mind looks like this but this is very bulky and I wonder if this could be done more elegantly:

```
catch (std::exception& e) {
    if (
#if defined(DEPLOYED)
       true
#else
       false
#endif
    ) {
        std::cerr << "Exception doing something " << e.what() << std::endl;
    } else {
        throw;
    }
#endif
}
```

Another example included a **variable rename** which was done everywhere (IDE supported "replace all occurrences) except in the `#if defined(DEPLOYED)` code blocks.

- Is it out of fashion to handle dev vs. deploy builds in C++ with `define`? If so, what is the recommended way?
- Especially when non-deployed code might contain computationally expensive calls, how do I make sure that they don't appear in deploy builds - maybe even can be optimized away completely?

Comment: Another "old school" way of working around this kind of problem is to add a `(void)e;` as the first line in the catch body.  Useful if you cannot use `[[maybe_unused]]` for whatever reason (although with C++17, that shouldn't be a problem).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it out of fashion to handle dev vs. deploy builds in C++ with `define`?

Not really, but it is not good practice to sprinkle `#ifdef`s in your business logic. It is a better idea to refactor the pieces that change between build modes into separate functions, and provide different implementations of those functions depending on the active build mode.

> How could this be written differently?

The [`[[maybe_unused]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused) attribute solves this problem elegantly.

```
catch ([[maybe_unused]] std::exception& e) {
#if defined(DEPLOYED)
    std::cerr << "Exception doing something " << e.what() << std::endl;
#else
    throw;
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it out of fashion to handle dev vs. deploy builds in C++ with
>   define? If so, what is the recommended way?

It would probably be better to drive this using a build system. The build system can then pull in the correct files/methods depending on if its a deployment or debug build

Your code could then look something like

```
catch (std::exception& e) 
{
    HandleError(e); 
}
```

where `HandleError` in a deployment build just logs but in a debug rethrows e.

> Especially when non-deployed code might contain computationally
>   expensive calls, how do I make sure that they don't appear in deploy
>   builds - maybe even can be optimized away completely?

This is guaranteed when using the build system as the unwanted files will never be compiled

Answer (score 0):

Some static analyzer tools (notably [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) and probably [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/)) are handling preprocessed C++ form. You could consider using them on the command line (and drive them from your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool, e.g. your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile))

And you could also (with several weeks or months of work) code your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html#Plugins) to interact with your favorite static analyzer or proof assistant. For inspiration, look into [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/).